# Is there a way to alter an <img> color in css?

Tags: css, image

So i created a PHP script for my work which generates HTML to display Social Media Icons if they are set to an associate array. when a website design need 2 different colors i normally have to generate the HTML and then use `str_replace` looking for the file extension and replacing it with a suffix fore the file extension, ie.

```
str_replace(".png", "-p.png", $SocialMediaMenu);
```

however for each color change i would need to copy and paste the .png files, give them a new pre/suffix and recolor them and currently we have 26 icons though i could expect this number to get bigger.

Now because i already size down the images from 100x100 with CSS i was thinking, is it possible to alter the `<img>`'s color using CSS that way i only need 1 set of images? and also what color (in hexadecimal) should my icons be as a base to allow maximum flexibility with the color edit as my current base set of images are white (#FFFFFF).

bellow is a pink version of one of the images i use

[image]

Comment: You need to look into SVGs or Glyph icons.  CSS cannot alter jpg, png, gif, etc.

Comment: The new CSS filter: directive might be able to do what you need, but it may be too new to be widely or stably supported.

Comment: You can use 100% white images with transparent background, and then alter the background's color easily with CSS.